# Using $_GET outside the while loop in which [''] is defined

Tags: php, get

For example, I have the following code:

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_thoughts WHERE added_by='$user' ORDER BY id DESC");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $thought_id      = $row['id'];
    $message_content = $row['message'];
    $date_of_msg     = $row['post_details'];
    $thoughts_by     = $row['added_by'];
    $attachent       = $row['attachment'];
    $shared          = $row['shared'];

    // for each post a user has made, a new div will be echo's
    echo    "
            <div class='message_wrapper'>
                // all content here which displays the message and author.
                // consider this anchor link, and see $_GET approach below.
                <a href='/inc/del_post.php?id=$thought_id>'>Delete </a> 
                <div id='toggleComment$thought_id' class='new_comment'>
                    <form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <textarea id='txtarea' name='comment_msg' cols='80' maxlength='180' placeholder=' add your comment...'></textarea> 
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input id='send' type='submit' name='send_comm' value='Share'/> 
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                         </table> 
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>";
} // while loop closed
// sending comments to database 
$comment = htmlentities(trim(strip_tags(@$_POST['comment_msg'])));
$comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $comment);

// if button is pressed, do this...
if(isset($_POST['send_comm'])){
    if (!empty ($comment)){
        $insert_comment = mysqli_query ($connect, "INSERT INTO user_comments VALUES ('','$comment','$username','$user','0','$thought_id')");
        header ("Location: /profile_page/$user");
    } 
}
?>
```

Before, I had the 'send_comm' processing in the while loop, and when I use to submit the form, the `comment` would be added to all of a users posts. For example, Alice has made two posts, I add a comment to one, both posts will display that message (and two new rows in db).

Now, to fix the above issue, I have put the 'send_comm' processing, outside the while loop,but of course, with this `$thought_id` (which in in my `INSERT`) would be undefined. Also, having it outside the while loop provides no way of the comment knowing which `thought_id` is is assigned to. So to fix this, I tried to use `$_GET`:

```
$thought_id_from_anchor = $_GET ['id'];

// if button is pressed, do this...
if(isset($_POST['send_comm'])){
    if (!empty ($comment)){
        $insert_comment = mysqli_query ($connect, "INSERT INTO user_comments VALUES ('','$comment','$username','$user','0','$thought_id_from_anchor')");
        header ("Location: /profile_page/$user");
    } 
}
```

But of course, since it is outside the while loop, I get an undefined error on `id`.

I just need a comment to be added to the `$thought_id` it is being added to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a `hidden` input to your form containing the value of `$thought_id`:

```
<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

    <input type='hidden' name='thought_id' value='$thought_id'>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea id='txtarea' name='comment_msg' cols='80' maxlength='180' placeholder=' add your comment...'></textarea> 
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id='send' type='submit' name='send_comm' value='Share'/> 
            </td>
        </tr>
     </table> 
</form>
```

Then when the form is submitted, you can access the value of `thought_id` using `$_POST` for your query (also cleaned it up a bit):

```
// if button is pressed, do this...
if (isset($_POST['send_comm'])) {

    $_POST = array_map('trim', $_POST);

    if (!empty($_POST['thought_id']) &&
        !empty($_POST['comment_msg'])) {

        $comment = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['comment_msg']));
        $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $comment);
        $thought_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['thought_id']);

        $insert_comment = mysqli_query ($connect, "INSERT INTO user_comments VALUES ('','$comment','$username','$user','0','$thought_id')");
        header ("Location: /profile_page/$user");
    }
    else {
        // empty fields; handle this accordingly
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO user_comments VALUES ('','$comment'
```

What is that empty string?

I think that is the ID, so, IDs only accepts integer values, you can replace by null, or remove it.

```
INSERT INTO user_comments VALUES (null,'$comment'

INSERT INTO user_comments VALUES ('$comment'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the id out side of the loop you will have to assing it >to a global variable.You will need to declare a variable in the global scope >and then use the global keyword with in the while loop. Once you do this you can use the thought_id variable any were you choose.

`<?php
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_thoughts WHERE added_by='$user' ORDER BY id DESC");


$thought_id; // Declare the variable outside of the while loop in the global scope 



 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {


      global  $thought_id      = $row['id']; 
 /*use the global keyword to assign the the value of this variable to the global variable and you will be able to use it out side of the while loop */


        $message_content = $row['message'];
        $date_of_msg     = $row['post_details'];
        $thoughts_by     = $row['added_by'];
        $attachent       = $row['attachment'];
        $shared          = $row['shared'];

        // for each post a user has made, a new div will be echo's
        echo    "
                <div class='message_wrapper'>
                    // all content here which displays the message and author.
                    // consider this anchor link, and see $_GET approach below.
                    <a href='/inc/del_post.php?id=$thought_id>'>Delete </a> 
                    <div id='toggleComment$thought_id' class='new_comment'>
                        <form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <textarea id='txtarea' name='comment_msg' cols='80' maxlength='180' placeholder=' add your comment...'></textarea> 
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id='send' type='submit' name='send_comm' value='Share'/> 
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                             </table> 
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>";
    } // while loop closed
    // sending comments to database 
    $comment = htmlentities(trim(strip_tags(@$_POST['comment_msg'])));
    $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $comment);

    // if button is pressed, do this...
    if(isset($_POST['send_comm'])){
        if (!empty ($comment)){
            $insert_comment = mysqli_query ($connect, "INSERT INTO user_comments VALUES ('','$comment','$username','$user','0','$thought_id')");
            header ("Location: /profile_page/$user");
        } 
    }
    ?>`